# iOS Private API for VPN

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, iphone-privateapi

I'm looking for some private API to start a VPN connection configured in the Settings app. Anyone any suggestions where I can find them?
The only thing I found is the ManagedConfiguration.framework. Is that the right place to start? it's kind a hard without any documentation :-/

P.S. I know private api can't be on the iTunes Store etc. This is only for private use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such api in the system configuration framework. But it's all Core Foundation. It's pretty hard to reverse engineere that. So I gave up on it.

Answer (score 3):

iOS 8.0 now includes the Network Extension framework. It is not documented on developer.apple.com, but in the 'Capabilities' pane, you just flip on 'Personal VPN' and it is added to the project for you... then you can browse its headers.
The [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreOSLayer/CoreOSLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH11-SW8) gives no deeper information. Grmbl.

I just discovered this and am now digging in, so I have no further insight, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

well this more than this: You can subscribe to App developer program and won't get access to the VPN API; You can even also subscribe to [Apple Entreprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) Apple support confirm that you will access to it, but you won't. 
You can ask to the famous "eskimo" guy to be invited and have acces but at the end only some of companies like Cisco, Juniper, and some others are granted to it.

So I confirm: you waste your time with this topic