# VPN Apple iOS hidden API

Tags: ios, ssl, vpn, iphone-privateapi

is someone have informations about Apple API to access SSL and VPN capabilities on iOS. 
Strangely, Apple doesn't communicate about it, asking them about is not answered whereas some software produced like Juniper, Cisco, etc did this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple pieces of information which I found on this:
http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2010/09/ios-4-1-undocumented-vpn-api-used-by-cisco-anyconnect/

[iOS Private API for VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742244/ios-private-api-for-vpn)

Comment: Thank you very much, this confirms that Apple is not willing to open anything, even to companies :" You can subscribe to App developer program and won't get access to the VPN API; You can even also subscribe to [Apple Entreprise program][1] Apple support confirm that you will access to it, but you won't. 
You can ask to the famous "eskimo" guy to be invited and have acces but at the end only some of companies like Cisco, Juniper, and some others are granted to it."


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 2):

iOS 8.0 now includes the Network Extension framework. It is not documented on developer.apple.com, but in the 'Capabilities' pane, you just flip on 'Personal VPN' and it is added to the project for you... then you can browse its headers.

I just discovered this and am now digging in, so I have no further insight, but there you go.

Comment: I just found the Network Extension framework in ios 8.1 only supports two major protocols, IPSec and IKEv2.You can program control connect or disconnect the vpn. I can not found a way to implement a custom protocol.